# docker container does not mount content of mapped volume on start

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have the following docker compose file which runs fine when I do `docker-compose up` but once I restart the machine, the container `php53` does not mount the content of `/home/madiba/Development/docker_test/www` to `/var/www. If I restart it's mounted! This is running on Ubuntu 16.04 server. Setting up the same container on my laptop running similar version of Ubuntu runs fine.

```
version: '2.0'

services:
db:

 image: mysql:5.5
 container_name: mysql5
 volumes:
   - "/home/madiba/Development/docker_test/mysql55_storage:/var/lib/mysql"

 ports:
   - "3355:3306"  
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass


php53:

 build: /home/madiba/Development/docker_test/php53
 container_name: php53

 ports:
   - "5533:80"
 volumes:
     - "/home/madiba/Development/docker_test/www:/var/www"

 depends_on:
   - db

 links:
   - db

 restart: always
 environment:
   display_errors: 'Off'
   PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER madiba <madiba@gmail.com>

# disable interactive functions
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

VOLUME ["/var/www"]

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
  apache2 \
  php5 \
  php5-cli \
  libapache2-mod-php5 \
  php5-gd \
  php5-ldap \
  php5-mysql \
  php5-pgsql \
  php5-mcrypt \
  php5-json \
  curl \
  libcurl3-dev \
  php5-curl \
  nano && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr /local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer --version


COPY apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
COPY run /usr/local/bin/run
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run
RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compose file does not seem to be indented correctly. The second line in the following section does not seem to have correct number of spaces at the beginning of the line. This could be an issue.

```
 volumes:
     - "/home/madiba/Development/docker_test/www:/var/www"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but in the log file, it shows the correct mapping.

Comment: `Thanks for the info but in the log file, it shows the correct mapping. `"Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/home/madiba/Development/www/docker_test/php53",
                "Destination": "/var/www",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],`